# New JHipster project: All integration tests fail

Tags: jhipster

Today, I tried starting a new project using JHipster. My environment includes:

```
Windows 10 22H2 build 19045.2251 (64 bit)
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-16.0.2+7
node 16.17.0
npm 8.19.1
Gradle 7.5.1
MariaDB 10.6.8
Chrome 107.0.5304.107
```

Project configuration file (myapp.jh) is:

```
application {
  config {
    baseName myapp,
    packageName com.mycompany.app,
    applicationType monolith,
    authenticationType jwt,
    cacheProvider ehcache,
    enableHibernateCache true,
    databaseType sql,
    devDatabaseType mariadb,
    prodDatabaseType mariadb,
    buildTool gradle,
    clientPackageManager npm,
    clientFramework angular,
    clientTheme minty,
    clientThemeVariant primary,
    testFrameworks [protractor, cypress],
    nativeLanguage en,
    languages [en, es],
    jhiPrefix myapp,
    jwtSecretKey "YjAwZDU2ODI3NzNjZjk0NjVhY2UzNGViZmY0YjY1ZGY2MDI5MTc5Y2FlZWYxNzE5Yjg5ZjMxOGZhZTgwZjA5NTFkN2VmNDM3ZGMyZDNjZTViNDAwYTg4NmNlMmM2ZDkxZTMwMDk5YmUxNWNkZmE0YTNiNDlhMGNhZmM4OTk1NmQ="
  }
}
```

I carried out the following steps in a shell command line:

- Installed the latest version of JHipster: `npm install -g generator-jhipster` --> **v7.9.3**
- Imported the JDL: `jhipster jdl myapp.jh`
- Built the application: `gradle build`

*Result*: Everything appears to build nicely up until the integration tests which **ALL fail**!

All integration tests for the latest version of JHipster fail in virtually the same way:

```
HibernateTimeZoneIT > storeLocalDateTimeWithZoneIdConfigShouldBeStoredOnGMTTimeZone() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804
            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:257
```

Naturally, the first line of each error varies according to each failing test, but the following lines (`java.lang.IllegalStateException ...` onward) are the same for ALL failed tests.  I have never seen errors like this before.  It appears to have something to do with Docker/MariadbTestContainer.

I repeated the steps for JHipster 7.9.2, and 7.9.0 -- with the same results -- all integration tests fail. (I even tried the maintenance build for 7.9.3, and get the same failures.)  I also get the same errors if I run the integration tests directly with: `gradle integrationTest`

You can see the `gradle --scan` output [here](https://scans.gradle.com/s/ur5vwgh7clgxo)

Finally, I downgraded to JHipster 7.8.1 (released in April), and everything works (no failures).

Are the last three JHipster releases (7.9.0, 7.9.2 and 7.9.3) broken? Has there been a new requirement introduced after v7.8.1?  Am I doing something wrong?

Please help!

(I'm happy to provide ANY additional information.)

**NOTE**: If I forego the integration tests, and just run the application (by typing `./gradlew` in one shell, and `npm start` in another shell, the application *does* run/work...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of JHipster makes use of docker test container instances (detailed in the `./README.md` file).  My docker instance was hosed. After reinstalling docker, everything works.

If you want the docker MariaDB test container instance to not interfere with a live instance of MariaDB running on your platform (default port 3306), you can change the docker port to something else (like 3308) by going into the `./src/main/docker/mariadb.yml` file, and find/change the ports configuration line to:

```yaml
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3308:3308
```

Now run your tests:

- Launch docker MariaDB test container: `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mariadb.yml up -d`
- Clean: `./gradlew clean`
- Build/test: `./gradlew build`
- (*Alternatively*, run integration tests: `./gradlew integrationTest`)

As an alternative, use the default JHipster database type:

```
devDatabaseType h2Disk
```

... and docker/MariaDB conflicts is not an issue. (The downside, of course, is that you will not be running your integration tests against an instance of MariaDB).

Answer (score 1):

I tried creating an app with 7.9.3 and your JDL on an M1 MacBook Pro. I'm using Java 17.

```
openjdk 17.0.5 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8, mixed mode)
```

I do get an error when it's creating.

```
npm WARN deprecated puppeteer@9.1.1: Version no longer supported. Upgrade to @latest

> myapp@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT postinstall
> npm run e2e:update-webdriver

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/mraible/Downloads/so/build/node/bin/npm
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mraible/Downloads/so/build/node/bin/npm:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/mraible/Downloads/so/build/node/bin/npm' ]
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/mraible/Downloads/so
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- npm run e2e:update-webdriver

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mraible/.npm/_logs/2022-11-15T20_26_11_345Z-debug-0.log
Error executing './npmw install', execute it yourself. (Command failed with exit code 1: ./npmw install)
```

After it completed, I tried running `./gradlew`. It fails again, likely related to Protractor.

```
> myapp@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT e2e:update-webdriver
> webdriver-manager update --gecko false

[13:29:25] I/file_manager - creating folder /Users/mraible/Downloads/so/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
[13:29:25] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/mraible/Downloads/so/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[13:29:25] I/config_source - curl -o/Users/mraible/Downloads/so/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

I ran `npm install` and it worked. I then tried `./gradlew` again. It failed to start because I don't have MariaDB running, so I started it using:

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mariadb.yml up -d
```

Now I'm able to start it and `npm run e2e` passes.

```
✔  All specs passed!                        00:33       33       33
```

When the tests ran with Cypress, I was surprised. Then I noticed you have both Cypress and Protractor specified as test frameworks. Since they do the same thing, and Protractor is deprecated, you should only use Cypress.

Next, I shut everything down and tried running the Java tests with:

```
npm run ci:backend:test
```

This runs:

```
./gradlew test integrationTest -x webapp -x webapp_test -Dlogging.level.ROOT=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.zalando=OFF -Dlogging.level.tech.jhipster=OFF -Dlogging.level.com.mycompany.app=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.web=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.security=OFF -Pprod
```

All tests pass for me:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 33s
```

Comment: Oooo.... I'll try it without protractor.... hold on...

Comment: Removed protractor, tried `./gradlew integrationTest` and get the same errors.  Also tried `npm run ci:backend:test` which returned an error: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command... (I'm going to go scratch my head some more.)  Also, when I copy/paste the long command you outlined above, I get all the same errors... All integration tests fail...

Comment: Also bumped by JDK to match yours... all integration tests fail (except in JHipster 7.8.1 where everything still works!!)... @matt-raible

Comment: Just for the heck of it, I created/tested the project again using maven @matt-raible. All integration tests fail again, and for the same/similar reasons, centered around Docker and MariadbTestContainer as noted above and visible in the Gradle scan logs...

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this on Windows 11. However, my error is not related to Docker. The error is `Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException at WindowsPathParser.java:182`. This is probably because I don't have Docker installed. I'll try installing Docker and report back.

Comment: I'm using a Mac M1 and I'm unable to install Docker Desktop on Windows (via Parallels) because it seems they don't have ARM64 support. https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-desktop-for-windows-arm/127478

Can you please enter an issue for this in the JHipster project? https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/new/choose